# Unable to process HTML with pandas

Tags: python, html, pandas

I'm trying to get the tables of this page source with pandas:

```
(in): html_source = driver.page_source
df_html = pd.read_html(html_source)

(out): TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U51') dtype('<U51') dtype('<U51')
```

The page itself contains multiple tables and graphs about assets. The html is very big and hence I'm pasting the link for it and for the tables I want to parse:

HTML: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbbsz30co99uveq/html_comdinheiro.html?dl=0

Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sc0vzafau94ymyr/comdinheiro.png?dl=0

Comment: You don't need the source, but at least paste the link.

Comment: Is the output of df_html a string? And yes, seeing the url would help

Comment: Added the link ^^. Sorry that they are in Portuguese.